# Get table view cell properties in UITableViewDelegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with custom table view cells. Their height depends on the amount of text that will appear in the cell. Here is my code for the UITableViewDelegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSDictionary *factor = [self.factorsArray objectAtIndex:row];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(260, kMaximumFactorLabelHeight);
    CGSize labelSize = [[factor objectForKey:@"text"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14.0]
                                 constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return (labelSize.height + 72);
}
```

This code works perfectly. My problem is that a number of things are hardcoded here:

- the width of the label in the table view cell
- the font name
- the font size
- "72" which is the extra height that needs to be added to the cell in addition to the label height.

I can get all of this information from the xib file containing the custom table view cell. But how do I get it in the heightForRowAtIndexPath:? I tried - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath but I was getting a crash, I believe because the cell doesn't exist yet when the heightForRowAtIndexPath method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it. I've usually had a class method on the UITableViewCell subclass to return the height based on the content passed in.

Comment: But how do I get, for example, the font of a label in the table view cell (that is defined in the xib file) in a class method?

Comment: You could load the nib and grab the proper information out of it. That's probably not the best way to do it though. When I have variable height cells, I don't use nibs and usually draw my text directly.

Comment: OK thanks, I need to get the information from the nib, because my client wants to be able to adjust the look by editing the nib file. I guess I'll load the nib file.